# Can't display drawings on screen when menu item is clicked.

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I have a two panels within a frame. The top control panel has a menu with three objects, square, circle and triangle. My frame implements the code from the top panel. I am having trouble at the moment to output the shapes on the screen when i select them from the menu. I have attached my top control panel and my MyFrame class. Thank you for any help, it is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my MyFrame class.

```
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener, ChangeListener {

public static Shapes shape1;
private JMenuItem Square;
private JMenuItem Triangle;
private JMenuItem Circle;
private jPanelTop d1 = new jPanelTop();
public MyFrame() {
    initComponents();

    MyControlPanel controlPanelShapes = new MyControlPanel();
    controlPanelShapes.setSize(1000, 1000);
    controlPanelShapes.setLocation(0, 20);
    add(controlPanelShapes);

    d1.setSize(400, 400);
    d1.setVisible(true);
    this.add(d1);

    JMenuBar jBarShape = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu Shape = new JMenu();
    Shape.setText("Shape");

    Square = new JMenuItem();
    Square.setText("Square");
    Shape.add(Square);
    Square.addActionListener(this);

    Triangle = new JMenuItem();
    Triangle.setText("Triangle");
    Shape.add(Triangle);
    Triangle.addActionListener(this);

    Circle = new JMenuItem();
    Circle.setText("Circle");
    Shape.add(Circle);
    Circle.addActionListener(this);

    jBarShape.add(Shape);
    setJMenuBar(jBarShape);

}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == Circle) {
        shape1 = new Circle();
        d1.setCircle();
    } else if (e.getSource() == Triangle) {
        shape1 = new Triangle();
    } else if (e.getSource() == Square) {
        shape1 = new Square();
        d1.setSquare();
    }
}
```

}

Here is my jPanel class:

```
public class jPanelTop extends javax.swing.JPanel {
public jPanelTop() {
    initComponents();
}
private int xPosition = 50;
private int yPosition = 50;
private Graphics g;

public void paintComponent() {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(xPosition, yPosition, 70, 70);
    g.drawOval(xPosition, yPosition, 70, 70);   
}

public void setSquare()
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(xPosition, yPosition, 70, 70);
    repaint();
}
public void setCircle()
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawOval(xPosition, yPosition, 70, 70);
    repaint();
}
```

}

I am extremely grateful for any help! :) Thanks!

Comment: Is this question related to **[this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076884/having-difficulty-with-actionlistener-jslider-jmenus-and-jlabels/20080133#20080133)**? This code looks familiar to me. If you had read **[my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076884/having-difficulty-with-actionlistener-jslider-jmenus-and-jlabels/20080133#20080133)** eventually had come to **[this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037558/adjust-shape-dimensions-using-a-jscrollbar/20058272#20058272)** where a `paintComponent` implementation is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your paintComponent is completely wrong as its signature does not match that of the super class. It needs to accept a Graphics parameter. And your JPanel class should **not** have a Graphics field.

For the drawing magic to occur, your drawing methods must override that of JComponents. You can test that you are not in fact doing this by adding an `@Override` annotation prior to  your paintComponent method. Do this and the compiler will complain to you that the method that you think is an override actually isn't (which is why using this annotation regularly is a very good idea -- you want the compiler to help you with your coding as much as possible). If your method does not override the super's method, it will never be called by the JVM.

Also, you shouldn't try to use Graphics directly in your setSquare and setCircle methods as you're doing. Again please read the tutorials to see how to do it right.

You will want to read the tutorials on how to draw. Key tutorial links:

- Basic Tutorial: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- More advanced information: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

---

On further evaluation of your code and problem, consider:

- Giving your drawing JPanel boolean variables, say `boolean drawCircle` and `boolean drawSquare`, and setting them to false.
- In your correct paintComponent override method, draw a circle if drawCircle is true, and same for square/drawSquare.
- In your setCircle method set drawCircle to true, drawSquare to false, and call repaint.
- Do the converse in your setSquare method.
- Learn and follow Java naming conventions: all class names should begin with an upper case letter. All method and field/variable names should begin with a lower case letter.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels looks like a `paintComponent`.